# Authorization Display & video 360 API

Tags: rest, postman, token, google-apis-explorer

I would like generate the token to google apis.
I'm using this url:
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

and the body is :

```
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: ***********
client_secret:*********
code:code
```

and I got the resposne :

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Malformed auth code."
}
```

Someone could help me to generate the token ?

Comment: can you see if my solution helped resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this error before and after trying out a few things, I figured it out. Can you try to add `access_type: 'offline'` to your request body?

Here is an example in `Node JS`: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#node.js_7

Comment: HIi @Dimitar, sorry but it's not working

Comment: @Anonim have you set the `include_granted_scopes` flag to `true`?